# If there is no nodes in current taxonomy term to display, load vocabulary and display other

Tags: views, nodes

*difficult to formulate a question*

I have made a View, which display `title, image, body(trimmed)` on nodes pages with Content type - `Home`, its related nodes to this one(. `Home` has different categories - taxonomy, for example looks like this:

1. Homes one
2. homes two
3. homes three

So for example if my current node has taxonomy term - `homes two` i should display only nodes`(title, image, body(trimmed)` of this term. I did it like this - with *contextual filters* `Content: Nid` - i exclude current node to not display it in my view and

```
Content: Has taxonomy term ID
```

When filter is not available - i provide my own value, php code:

```
 $node = node_load(arg(1));
 if($node) {
 foreach($node->field_home_category[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $term) { 
    $terms[] = $term['tid']; 
 }
    return implode('+',$terms);
  } 
  else { 
    return
  }
```

`$node->field_home_category[LANGUAGE_NONE]` -  is a field which contains taxonomy term id.

And its works fine, but if my node is only single in `homes two` taxonomy term, the view returns nothing(for obvious reasons) and if this happens i need to display any other `Home` nodes.

I think i should load my taxonomy vocabulary and get all the terms and pass them to my view in this situation. Like this:

```
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree(2); // vocabulary id - is 2
    foreach ($tree as $term) {
        $options[] = $term->tid;
      }
      return implode('+', $options);
```

**but i dont know how to add this to my view.**

Something like this ->

**PSEUDO CODE:**

```
IF THERE IS NO NODES IN CURRENT TERM
   DO 
      LOAD VOCABULARY OF HOMES
    AND 
      DISPLAY ANY AVALIABLE NODES OF THIS VOCABULARY
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**I will post full solution, maybe helps someone:**

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

No results behavior is great, but there is few situations:

For example:

```
homes two contains 2 homes, one is excluded, so view will display only 1 home, but we need 3 homes to be displayed all the time.
```

What i did is created new view, which displays 3 homes randomly(global Random sort criteria)
and excluded `nid` in contextual filter, i allow to pass multiple values to `nid`.
and in `THEME_views_pre_render(&$view)` i did next thing:

```
function THEME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'home') { // check is this my view
      $args = $view->args; //passed arguments
      $results = &$view->result; // this is important , you should pass it by reference
      if (!empty($args) && isset($args[0]) && isset($args[1])) {
        $node = node_load($args[1]);
        if ($node->type == 'home') { // check node type
            foreach($view->result as $row) {
                $restricted[] = $row->nid; //push current nodes to array, to pass them later to our new view, to not display them
            }
            $result_count = count($view->result);
            switch ($result_count) {
                case 1: // if one home
                    //gett the results of my view which display all nodes
                    // and do not display node which already displayed
                    // aka $restricted array
                    $result_array = views_get_view_result('related_homes_and_features', 'block_3', $restricted);
                    //add this results to current view
                    //
                    array_push($results, $result_array[0],$result_array[1]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $result_array = views_get_view_result('related_homes_and_features', 'block_3', $restricted);
                    array_push($results, $result_array[0]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $result_array = views_get_view_result('related_homes_and_features', 'block_3');
                    array_push($results, $result_array[0], $result_array[1], $result_array[2]);
                    return;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

home that helps someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **"No results behavior"** of the view ; specify a new view ("Global: View area"), showing all nodes, *excluding* the taxonomy term "homes two".

Comment: i resolved it by adding `("Global: PHP")` and added `views_embed_view` - embed my new view which displays all the nodes.

Comment: added full solution to my question.

Comment: nice :)
Is there any chance you could gain some performance by using views_pre_build ?